# Pulling records by parent ID with visualforce SLDS remote objects

Tags: visualforce, javascript, remote-objects, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm trying to pull fields in my custom object by matching it with the parent Id in Visualforce with the new Lightning design. I've done it with Apex but am a little confused with remote objects. I believe I have the code right, but it won't render. Any ideas?

What I used to do with Apex would be below and I would render it by extending it as a controller.

`private List<Custom_Object__c> ObjectList;
public List<Custom_Object__c> getObjectList()
{
  Opportunity opp = [Select Id FROM Opportunity where Id = :Opp.Id];
  if (opp.Id == null)
    return null;
  ObjectList = [Select Id, Name, ObjectParentId, CustomField1, CustomField2, CustomField3
  FROM Custom_Object__c
  WHERE ObjectParentId = :Opp.Id
  ORDER by CreateDate acs limit 1];
  return ObjectList
}`

And here is my what I'm currently trying to do with javascript and remote object

`<apex:remoteObjects> 
   <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Custom_Object__c"
   fields="Id, Name, ObjectParentId, CustomField1, CustomField2, CustomField3"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>`

Javascript......

```
<script>
      var sap = new SObjectModel.Custom_Object__c();
      var outputDiv = documet.getElementById("objectList");
      function updateOutputDiv() {    

        sap.retrieve({
          WHERE: {ObjectParentId: {eq: '{!Opportunity.Id}'},
          ORDERBY: [{CreateDate: 'ASC'}], limit: 1,
          }, 
          function(error, records) {
            if (error) {
              alert(error.message);
            } else {
                  var html = '<div class="slds-scrollable--x"><table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">';    

              html += '<thead><tr><th scope="col">Custom Object Subject</th>';
              html += '<th scope="col">Custom Object Data</th></tr></thead><tbody>';    


              records.forEach(function(record) {
                  html += '<tr><td>' + record.get("CustomField1") + '</td>';
                  html += '<td>' + record.get("CustomField2") + '</td>';
                  html += '<td>' + record.get("CustomField3") + '</td></tr>';
              });
              html = html + '</tbody></table></div>';
              outputDiv.innerHTML = html;
              });
            }
         });
      }
      updateOutputDiv();
</script>
```

And then my Visualforce html

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="OppCtrlExtSAP">
    <vs:importvisualstrap theme="paper"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS080, 'assets/styles/salesforce lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
       <div class="slds">
          <div class="myapp">
             <div id="objectList" class="slds-p-vertical--medium"></div>
          </div>
       </div
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix up your JSON query object, as it is written now it is malformed. You are missing a `}` after the Where clause, and after your limit clause there should not be a `,` character.

```
{
  where:{ObjectParentId: {eq: '{!Opportunity.Id}'}},
  orderby: [{CreateDate: 'ASC'}], 
  limit: 1
}
```

Also looking at the [Format and Options for Remote Objects Query Criteria](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm?search_text=remote%20object) documentation all key words ("where", "orderby", etc) are in lower case.  I don't know how Salesforce handles these on their end, but since Javascript is case sensitive I would keep them all lower case.

> ```
> var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact();
> ct.retrieve( 
>     { where: { 
>         FirstName: {eq: 'Marc'}, 
>         LastName: {eq: 'Benioff'} 
>     }, 
>     orderby: [ {LastName: 'ASC'}, {FirstName: 'ASC'} ],
>     limit: 1 },  
>     function(err, records) { 
>         if (err) { 
>             alert(err); 
>         } else { 
>             console.log(records.length); 
>             console.log(records[0]); 
>         } 
>     } 
> );
> ```

Finally, I don't know how the `'{!Opportunity.Id}'` merge field would work in the JSON object.  You may try assigning the value to a variable outside of the JSON object and then using the variable.

Answer (score 0):

1)Are you calling your function properly ?Do you see any issues in your console to see if JS error has happened .

First look at it says for SLDS your entire code should be wrapped in SLDS container div like below

```
   <div id="content" class="slds">
       <div class="myapp">
       <div id="objectList" class="slds-p-vertical--medium"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

I did this but with little React JS there ,in case you are interested

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2015/09/reactjs-and-salesforce-lightning-slds.html

Comment: Hi Mohith, I do have the slds class wrapped in my code. Sorry for not including it. Thanks for letting me know though. I'll edit it

Comment: Do you see any error in console .You can console.log the whole object that comes from Visualforce Remote Objects

Comment: Hi Mohith, thanks for the response. There are no errors in my console and I've also tried console logging and have no real results to show.